# INSERT multiple lines with for loop that uses $key => $value pairs

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm a complete newbie and this one has my stomped for hours. I have tried a couple of ways and will try to share what I have so far.

I'm designing a website that will allow golfers to post their scores online.
At he moment I'm designing the form where the admin creates courses and then the tricky part.... to add the holes to the course.

What I have done is to create the course in the DB and now I need to link the holes to the course.

Here is the part of the form that creates the table for the data:

```
    <?php
for($i=1;$i<=9;$i++)
 {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>$i</td>";
  echo "<div class='col-xs-3'>";
  echo "<td><input class='form-control' type='number' id='h$i.meter' name='h$i.meter' value='' required value=''></td>";
  echo "</div>";
  echo "<div class='col-xs-3'>";
  echo "<td><input class='form-control' type='number' id='h$i.par' name='h$i.par' value='' required value=''></td>";
  echo "</div>";
  echo "<div class='col-xs-3'>";
  echo "<td><input class='form-control' type='number' id='h$i.si' name='h$i.si' value='' required value=''></td>";
  echo "</div>";
  echo "</tr>";
 }
?>
```

This creates a nice table and if I do a:

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_POST);
echo'</pre>';
?>
```

I get the following output: I just added 1's in all the fields

```
array (size=28)
  'action' => string 'holes_add' (length=9)
  'h1_meter' => string '1' (length=1)
  'h1_par' => string '1' (length=1)
  'h1_si' => string '1' (length=1)
  'h2_meter' => string '1' (length=1)
  'h2_par' => string '1' (length=1)
  'h2_si' => string '11' (length=2)
  'h3_meter' => string '1' (length=1)
  'h3_par' => string '1' (length=1)
  'h3_si' => string '1' (length=1)
  'h4_meter' => string '1' (length=1)
  'h4_par' => string '1' (length=1)
  'h4_si' => string '1' (length=1)
  'h5_meter' => string '1' (length=1)
  'h5_par' => string '1' (length=1)
  'h5_si' => string '1' (length=1)
  'h6_meter' => string '1' (length=1)
  'h6_par' => string '11' (length=2)
  'h6_si' => string '1' (length=1)
  'h7_meter' => string '1' (length=1)
  'h7_par' => string '1' (length=1)
  'h7_si' => string '1' (length=1)
  'h8_meter' => string '1' (length=1)
  'h8_par' => string '1' (length=1)
  'h8_si' => string '1' (length=1)
  'h9_meter' => string '1' (length=1)
  'h9_par' => string '1' (length=1)
  'h9_si' => string '1' (length=1)
```

This tells me that the POST data is created and I can use it to store in my DB.

The problem is there is 18 holes in total and to do INSERT statements for all of them seems untidy.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO holes
                            (courseID,holeNo,par,stroke,meters)
                        VALUES
                        ('$courseID', '1', '$h1_par', '$h1_si', '$h1_meter'),
                        ('$courseID', '2', '$h2_par', '$h2_si', '$h2_meter'),
                        ('$courseID', '3', '$h3_par', '$h3_si', '$h3_meter'),
                        ('$courseID', '4', '$h4_par', '$h4_si', '$h4_meter'),
                        ('$courseID', '5', '$h5_par', '$h5_si', '$h5_meter'),
                        ('$courseID', '6', '$h6_par', '$h6_si', '$h6_meter'),
                        ('$courseID', '7', '$h7_par', '$h7_si', '$h7_meter'),
                        ('$courseID', '8', '$h8_par', '$h8_si', '$h8_meter'),
                        ('$courseID', '9', '$h9_par', '$h9_si', '$h9_meter'),
                        ('$courseID', '10', '$h10_par', '$h10_si', '$h10_meter'),
                        ('$courseID', '11', '$h11_par', '$h11_si', '$h11_meter'),
                        ('$courseID', '12', '$h12_par', '$h12_si', '$h12_meter'),
                        ('$courseID', '13', '$h13_par', '$h13_si', '$h13_meter'),
                        ('$courseID', '14', '$h14_par', '$h14_si', '$h14_meter'),
                        ('$courseID', '15', '$h15_par', '$h15_si', '$h15_meter'),
                        ('$courseID', '16', '$h16_par', '$h16_si', '$h16_meter'),
                        ('$courseID', '17', '$h17_par', '$h17_si', '$h17_meter'),
                        ('$courseID', '18', '$h18_par', '$h18_si', '$h18_meter')";
```

That is just a "demo" to show how it will look like, I use PDO and prepared statements for the "real" code.

So here is what I have been playing around with to get the POST data and try to insert with a foreach. I use a MVC model and this part is in my controller. If I just add one hole at a time everything runs and inserts the data. I'm not gonna add the code that is not relevant for my question.

```
    for($i=1;$i<=18;$i++)
    {
      $hole_id = add_hole("$course_id, $i, ‘$h’ . $i . ‘_par’,
 '$h’ . $i . ‘_si’, ‘$h’ . $i . ‘_meter'");
```

Here is the function for "add_hole" that adds the data in the DB:

```
function add_hole($course_id, $holeNo, $h1_par, $h1_si,$h1_meter) {
    global $db;
    $query = 'INSERT INTO holes
                 (courseID,holeNo,par,stroke,meters)
              VALUES
                 (:course_id, :holeNo, :h1_par, :h1_si, :h1_meter)';
    try {
        $statement = $db->prepare($query);
        $statement->bindValue(':course_id', $course_id);
        $statement->bindValue(':holeNo', $holeNo);
        $statement->bindValue(':h1_par', $h1_par);
        $statement->bindValue(':h1_si', $h1_si);
        $statement->bindValue(':h1_meter', $h1_meter);        
        $statement->execute();
        $statement->closeCursor();

        // Get the last hole ID that was automatically generated
        $hole_id = $db->lastInsertId();
        return $hole_id;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $error_message = $e->getMessage();
        display_db_error($error_message);
    }
}
```

And this is where I'm stuck. I have tried to implement the foreach loop as above, I have tried to concatenate with {} and . and "" and '' but I just cant seem to pass the variables to the function.

I know this is a looong question and there might be a couple of questions regarding some of the code. But any help or nudge in the correct direction will be highly appreciated. I know that I will run in similar problems with the rest of my site because of the 18 holes that needs to be managed the whole time and if I can get this sorted out it should go a long way,

Thanks
Gerhard

EDIT:
Ok, so what i have done is save my form data as an array by doing this:

```
<?php
for($i=1;$i<=9;$i++)
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><input class='form-control' type='hidden' name='hole[$i][no]' value='$i' '>$i</td>";
echo "<td><input class='form-control' type='number' name='hole[$i][meter]' value='' required value=''></td>";
echo "<td><input class='form-control' type='number' name='hole[$i][par]' value='' required value=''></td>";
echo "<td><input class='form-control' type='number' name='hole[$i][si]' value='' required value=''></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

This gives me a nice array to work with:

```
array (size=9)
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      'no' => string '1' (length=1)
      'meter' => string '1' (length=1)
      'par' => string '1' (length=1)
      'si' => string '1' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array (size=4)
      'no' => string '2' (length=1)
      'meter' => string '1' (length=1)
      'par' => string '1' (length=1)
      'si' => string '1' (length=1)
```

..... etc

Now I have to figure out how to take that array and do the DB INSERT...

---

EDIT -> SOLUTION !!!!!!

Ok, so what I have done is as follow. All html and css have been excluded and remember I use MVC. In the page there is two forms, one loops from 1 to 9 and the other loops from 10 to 18 to make the 18 holes for the course. I will implement a radio button for the user to select if it is a 9 or 18 hole course and the appropriate forms will be displayed or omitted.

In the form:

```
<?php
for($i=1;$i<=9;$i++)
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><input class='form-control' type='hidden' name='holeNo[]' id='holeNo[]' value='$i' '>$i</td>";
echo "<td><input class='form-control' type='number' name='meters[]' id='meters[]' value='' required value=''></td>";
echo "<td><input class='form-control' type='number' name='par[]' id='par[]' value='' required value=''></td>";
echo "<td><input class='form-control' type='number' name='stroke[]' id='stroke[]' value='' required value=''></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

This gives me a nice 2d array to work with:

```
array (size=5)
  'action' => string 'holes_add' (length=9)
  'holeNo' => 
    array (size=9)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string '2' (length=1)
      2 => string '3' (length=1)
      3 => string '4' (length=1)
      4 => string '5' (length=1)
      5 => string '6' (length=1)
      6 => string '7' (length=1)
      7 => string '8' (length=1)
      8 => string '9' (length=1)
  'meters' => 
    array (size=9)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string '1' (length=1)
      2 => string '1' (length=1)
      3 => string '1' (length=1)
      4 => string '1' (length=1)
      5 => string '1' (length=1)
      6 => string '1' (length=1)
      7 => string '1' (length=1)
      8 => string '1' (length=1)
  'par' => 
    array (size=9)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string '1' (length=1)
      2 => string '1' (length=1)
      3 => string '1' (length=1)
      4 => string '1' (length=1)
      5 => string '1' (length=1)
      6 => string '1' (length=1)
      7 => string '1' (length=1)
      8 => string '1' (length=1)
  'stroke' => 
    array (size=9)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string '1' (length=1)
      2 => string '1' (length=1)
      3 => string '1' (length=1)
      4 => string '1' (length=1)
      5 => string '1' (length=1)
      6 => string '1' (length=1)
      7 => string '1' (length=1)
      8 => string '1' (length=1)
```

And in my Controller I just do this:

```
case 'holes_add':
            add_hole();            
            redirect($app_path . 'admin/course');
        break;
```

And in my model I do the following:

```
function add_hole() {
    global $db;
    $keys = array_keys($_POST['holeNo']);
    foreach ( $keys as $key ) {
        $course_id = ($_POST['course_id']);
        $holeNo = ($_POST['holeNo'][$key]);
        $par = ($_POST['par'][$key]);
        $stroke = ($_POST['stroke'][$key]);
        $meters = ($_POST['meters'][$key]);
        $query = "
            insert into holes
                    (courseID,holeNo,par,stroke,meters)
                VALUES
                    (:course_id, :holeNo, :par, :stroke, :meters)
        ";
        $statement = $db->prepare($query);
        $statement->bindValue(':course_id', $course_id);
        $statement->bindValue(':holeNo', $holeNo);
        $statement->bindValue(':par', $par);
        $statement->bindValue(':stroke', $stroke);
        $statement->bindValue(':meters', $meters);
        $statement->execute();
    }
        try {
        $statement->closeCursor();
         //Get the last hole ID that was automatically generated
            $hole_id = $db->lastInsertId();
             return $hole_id;
         } catch (PDOException $e) {
             $error_message = $e->getMessage();
             display_db_error($error_message);
         }
     }
```

That adds the data into the DB and puts a smile on my face :-)

I use PDO and prepared statements so I hope that im not open to SQL injection.

I hope this helps someone someday...

PLUR
G

Comment: You can bind multiple values at once if you have an associative array. That's usually way less code.

Comment: What happens if someone wants to register a 9 hole course

Comment: what do you get when you echo the inputs just before the function call?

Comment: Also, here's a link to pastebin which will give you the CS50 function call for mysql. [link](http://pastebin.com/zrT1saKX)'CS50'

Comment: You are making your life harder than it needs to be the way you are naming your form fields. Go research how `[` and `]` can be used in the name attribute to automatically create array data structures below $_POST.

Comment: @CBroe I have done that now, see my EDIT at the bottom of my post. I found a way to work with the array and insert the data. I must just figure it out...

Answer (score 0):

See the bottom of the original post for the solution I implemented...

Comment: Move prepare outside the loop